# Newbie CSS: Dropdown Menu Appears without Menu Hover?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm new here and new at HTML and CSS.

I've been trying to create a dropdown menu, and while the drop down menu shows up upon menu hover, it also shows up without menu hover. As soon as I move my cursor within where the dropdown should be appearing, it appears. Do you know what I'm doing wrong and how I should correct it? I hope I'm making sense...

Also, I am aware that the width of my menu expands as I expand the window size. Please ignore that, it doesn't do that in the main code I'm working on.

Thanks in advance!

```css
.top-menu>ul {
  background-color: #78a1bb;
  font-size: 150%;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.top-menu>ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 124px;
  position: relative;
}

.top-menu>ul>li:hover {
  background-color: #d6e2ea;
}

ul.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 290px;
  background-color: #d6e2ea;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
}

ul.sub-menu li {
  font-size: 80%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.top-menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="top-menu">
  <ul>
    <li> A
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Sub a </li>
        <li>Sub b </li>
        <li>Sub c </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> B </li>
    <li> C </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: It would be very useful if you post a plunker with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use `opacity` to hide your `sub-menu`. You can use `display: none` to hide and `display: block` to show again.

If you just change the opacity, the element remains "under your mouse" and the CSS try to show and hide many times (your sub-menu is "flicking").

Using `display: none` the sub-menu disappears and your mouse doesn't hover it "forever".

I created a plunker with the right code. https://embed.plnkr.co/TZ7U0m19WijN0kIe6Xgl/

Comment: Thanks for explaining!